# Git ignore on a folder?

Tags: git, wildcard, gitignore

If I have a folder called 'test' in my root, how do I put ignore so that the folder and all files/folders in it would be on gitignore? I've tried various tutorials, but nothing seems to be working. I bet its a very quick job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a wildcard: add

```
test/**
```

to the `.gitignore`.

In *Linux*, a simple command to do this is:

```
echo 'test/**' >> .gitignore
```

in the root of the repository.

The `**` unifies with all files in the directory and beyond.

This is sound with the [`.gitignore` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Two consecutive asterisks (`"**"`) in patterns matched against full
>   pathname may have special meaning:
>
> - A leading `"**"` followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, `"**/foo"` matches file or directory `"foo"` anywhere, the
>     same as pattern `"foo"`. `"**/foo/bar"` matches file or directory `"bar"`
>     anywhere that is directly under directory `"foo"`.
> - A trailing `"/**"` matches everything inside. For example, `"abc/**"` matches all files inside directory `"abc"`, relative to the location of
>     the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, `"a/**/b"` matches `"a/b"`,
>     `"a/x/b"`, `"a/x/y/b"` and so on.
> - Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.

(syntax modification, but same text).

Answer (score 1):

You need `.gitignore` in your projects directory. Add the following:

```
dir_to_ignore/**
```

More info [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

> A trailing `/**` matches everything inside. For example, `dir_to_ignore/**`
>   matches all files inside directory `dir_to_ignore`, relative to the location of
>   the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.